# Which cases are not counted here?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Q)Let 15 toys be distributed among 3 children subject to the condition that any child can take any number of toys. Find the required number of ways to do this if the toys are distinct.

This question can be easily answered as there are 3 children for each toy to go to, hence $3^{15}=14348907$
is the correct answer. However, if we look at it through different(wrong) way, the first child can get any one of 15 toys, the second one can get can get remaining 14, the third 13 making it total of $15*14*13=2730$ which is very low as compared to other and I can't figure out why, as all children are counted for?Which cases are not counted here?

Comment: There are $12$ toys that remain undistributed, and also each child may choose to not take any toy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$15 \times 14 \times 13$ would be the correct answer if each child only gets to pick one toy, and the other toys are left unclaimed.

Which is to say: the cases covered by the $2\,730$ answer aren't among the cases covered by the $14\,348\,907$ answer, and vice versa.  They count completely disjoint scenarios!

Actually -- I'm not sure $3^{15}$ is the correct answer either!  The children could all think that certain toys just aren't any fun and leave them behind, which would make the true result $4^{15} = 1\,073\,741\,824$, and the cases *that* covers include both the case in which every toy is claimed, and the case in which each child claims exactly one toy.

Comment: It is given in my book as 3^15 but you are quite right.